# NFS share becomes unresponsive and prevents programs from functioning

Tags: networking, server, mount, nfs, transmission

Ive got a server with transmission, and a few other programs running. Im trying to connect to a WD My cloud network drive. Ive got it mounted as an NFS share, but if I use LS or have a program acsess it, everything hangs and never becomes responsive. I belive if I turn off the colors for ls it will work. So its something file related I guess.

One weird thing, I had been backing up to it using crashplan on windows, but I decided to try moving it to a new share since it puts a ton of files on the drive and makes searching take forever. Once I removed it, suddenly it worked. Then I added 2 torrents to Transmission and things downloaded for a bit, and the issue came back suddenly.

Anyone got any ideas? I really want to be able to use this drive since it wasnt exactly cheap, and I cant expand the storage in my server machine, its an older HP media slim machine. So theres no room to expand it. Its not super old, it had vista on it, so it shouldnt be a lack of hardware power.

Comment: that usually happens if you have an unreliable connection to the nfs server.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen could it be on the computer its self? My windows PC doesnt have an issue with it

Comment: Hard to know where the problem is with what little you posted. Start debugging - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147308/system-lock-up-when-storage-go-offline-when-using-nfs-mount-options-bg-hard-noin and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31979/stop-broken-nfs-mounts-from-locking-a-directory. Samba may be a better option if you have windows servers or clients.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to mostly have been related to NFS protocol taking up a ton of CPU. Moving to local downloads, then transfering the complete file to the NFS share has fixed most of my issues